# Find all ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}]$

Tags: linear-algebra, ideals

The ring $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}]=\{\frac{u}{2^n}\}$ is the localization of $\mathbb{Z}$ in regards to $S=\{2^n:n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. Find all ideals of this ring.

I'm not sure what is meant by this question. The ideals should be of the form $(2^n u)$ since $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}]$ has no other elements to form linear combinations?

Comment: Do you know the theorem that if $I\subseteq S^{-1}A$ is an ideal in the localization, then $I = S^{-1}J = \{\frac{x}{s}\mid x\in J,s\in S\}$ for some ideal $J\subseteq A$? Now since you (presumably) know all ideals in $\mathbb{Z}$, you have a description of all ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}]$. It remains to determine when two such ideals are equal...

Comment: What does "no other elements to form linear combinations" mean?

Comment: What is your $u$? (twice). Why do you put $2^n$ in your $(2^nu)$? ($2$ is invertible)

Answer (score 1):

Let $I$ be an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$, then $I\cap\mathbb{Z}$ is an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$ so it is of the form $\alpha\mathbb{Z}$ with $\alpha\in\mathbb{N}$. I claim that $I=\alpha\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$. Indeed $\alpha\in I$ so $\alpha\mathbb{Z}[1/2]\subseteq I$, on the other hand if $x=\frac{a}{2^n}\in I$ then $2^nx=a\in I\cap\mathbb{Z}$ so $a=\alpha m$ for some $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ and therefore $x=\alpha\frac{m}{2^n}\in\alpha\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$.

Comment: What happens when $a$ is even?

Comment: Anything can happen, if $\alpha$ is a power of $2$ then it is invertible in $\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$ so $I=\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$, if $\alpha=6$ then it is a strict ideal for instance.

Comment: A complete answer to this question should not just prove that every ideal in $R = \mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}]$ has the form $nR$ for $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, but also identify when two such ideals are equal. In fact, every ideal in $R$ has the form $nR$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$ with $n = 0$ or $n$ odd, and these ideals are all distinct.